# Binary representation of quadratic surd number

Tags: number-theory, binary, continued-fractions

We know that every quadratic surd number has a periodic continued fraction. For example $\sqrt{3}=[1;1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,...]=[1;\overline{1,2}]$. Is this number has a special binary representation?

Comment: The binary representation of $\sqrt{3}$ shows no pattern. In general , no pattern seems to appear if we convert any algebraic irrational number to any base.